# Nothing happening after the fgetcsv loop. Trying to save data from a tab delimitted report from amazon mws api

Tags: php, fgetcsv, fileparsing

```
while ($keys = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) {

        if ($c == 0) {
            $headers = $keys;

        } else {
            $rows[] = $keys;
            //var_dump($keys);
        }

         $c ++;
    }

fclose($fp);
echo count($rows);
```

If I echo the `$count` it works fine(shows the proper count), even if I dump the keys (commented line) it echoes as expected, but nothing happens after the loop ends. at around 9154 rows;

These lines below don't work and the script execution stops without any apparent error.

```
fclose($fp);
echo count($rows);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as in the PHP manual:

```
while( ( $keys = fgetcsv( $fp, 0, "\t" ) ) !== FALSE ) {
```

Also, make sure your input csv has a clean end of file.

Comment: You need double quotes around that `\t`.

Comment: $data = stream_get_contents($request->getReport()); i believe then its and eof issue, tried a third party parser class, with same behavior, so I assume its an EOF issue. whats the best way to add an eof.

Comment: !== FALSE did the trick, i was fighting without knowing my options! thanks

Comment: @RashidShafique No problem, variables store boolean (true/false) as 0 or 1, so make sure you're using strict comparisons in conditions that declare/assign a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell us what happens:

```
// make sure we see all errors
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

// read the entire file into an array, one element per row
$rows = array();
while($fields = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) {
    $rows[] = $fields;
}
fclose($fp);

// handle empty CSV case
if(count($rows) == 0) {
    die('CSV is empty');
}

$headers = $rows[0];
```

Comment: i tried that and it just doesnt execute beyond the fgetcsv loop, thinking its eof issue, since msw api returns data in streaming manner, its captured in $data var which I write to a file using     $fp = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
fwrite($fp, $x);
rewind($fp);

Comment: Fair enough. A very low-tech way would be to copy and paste the CSV content into a new file, minus the last visible character. Then retype that character and save...